# Fallo al utilizar egulias/EmailValidator

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de implementar validación dns de dominio y cuentas spoof para una aplicación en PHP y encontré la librería https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator

Mi código:

```
use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\MultipleValidationWithAnd;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\DNSCheckValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\SpoofCheckValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;



$validator = new EmailValidator();

$validator->isValid("example@example.com", new RFCValidation());
```

He seguido las instrucciones, según la documentación esa función me debería devolver un booleano pero me devuelve un objeto.

Alguien que la haya utilizado sabe que es lo que me falta?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Asigna una variable asi: `$valor = $validator->isValid("example@example.com", new RFCValidation());` añade `var_dump($valor)` y adjunta lo que te aparezca por favor

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar. Esa era la solución. Cuando hago el var_dump de la variable ya si que me devuelve un booleano. Yo estaba haciendo un var_dump de $validator, por eso me devolvía un objeto.